# Retrieve data from database in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a table in my database called `modules` so in my controller I write like this to retrieve datas from the table

```
 $allModuleNames = DB::table('users')->get();
 return view("BaseView.home")->with('$allModuleNames',$allModuleNames);
```

But for some weird reason I am getting `syntax error, unexpected ';'`  error on the query like. This must be silly I guess,not able to pass through this. Can someone help?
I have added this to the header

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

And when I hover over `table` I get `method table not found in \illuminate\Support\Faces\DB`

Comment: well, sorry but, there are so many issues in the code you posted that is difficult to guess what is really wrong. The table is "modules" and you are retrieving from "users". The with() should be ->with('allModuleNames',$allModuleNames). Where did you hover? To call the DB facade use \DB::table().

Comment: that was a typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `modules` intead of `users` :

```
$allModuleNames = DB::table('modules')->get();
```

and you dont need the `$` on this line :

```
return view("BaseView.home")->with('allModuleNames',$allModuleNames);
```

Comment: That was not the issue in my my loop. Sorry about that. Anyway thanks :)